# Why Page Control of Datatables Not Linear?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, datatables

I got one problem, the page button of my datatables out of line. I used SB admin templates (bootstrap). I tried to edit my datatables function, but it's not working.

My page is like follows

[datatables view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8clOK.jpg)

but I want it like this

[datatables view2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kjMI.jpg)

this is my datatables code :

```
<script>
      $('#datatables').dataTable
        ({  
            "sScrollX": "200%", //This is what made my columns increase in size.
            "bScrollCollapse": true,
            "sScrollY": "800px",

            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "aoColumns": [
                { "sWidth": "5%" }, // 1st column width 
                { "sWidth": "null" }, // 2nd column width 
                { "sWidth": "80%" }, // 3rd column width
                { "sWidth": "null" }, // 4th column width 
                { "sWidth": "null" }, // 5th column width 
                { "sWidth": "50%" }, // 6th column width
                { "sWidth": "null" }, // 7th column width 
                { "sWidth": "null" }, // 8th column width 
                { "sWidth": "null" }, // 9th column width
                { "sWidth": "80%" }, // 10th column width
                { "sWidth": "80%" }, // 11th column width
                { "sWidth": "null" },
                { "sWidth": "null" },
                { "sWidth": "null" },
                { "sWidth": "null" },
                { "sWidth": "null" },
                ],

            "bPaginate": true,            
            "sDom": '<"search"f><"top"l>rt<"bottom"ip><"clear">',
            "sPaginationType":"full_numbers",
            "aaSorting":[[0, "asc"]],
            "bJQueryUI":true    

        });
</script>
```

I'm sorry my English is not good.. but, please help me..

Comment: Would be nice to have a JSFiddle to look at? Also 5% + 80% + 50% + 80% + 80% = 295%... might that have something to do with your issue?

Comment: I think no.. I tried to edit JSFiddle, but it's not work.